# Hyperledger Sawtooth Input and Output values

Tags: python, hyperledger, hyperledger-sawtooth

I followed this tutorial: https://sawtooth.hyperledger.org/docs/core/releases/1.0/app_developers_guide.html

I set up a node with docker, which seems to be working.
However when I do the transaction with the python SDK [as described here](https://sawtooth.hyperledger.org/docs/core/releases/1.0/_autogen/sdk_submit_tutorial_python.html) I am getting the response "Invalid Resource Id" from the validator api.

I am not sure but it's possible that the problem are the inputs and outputs for the transaction. I just used the ones from the docs, do I have to change those?
There is a short explanation [here](https://sawtooth.hyperledger.org/docs/core/releases/1.0/architecture/transactions_and_batches.html#dependencies-and-input-output-addresses) but I don't understand what to do with it.

Edit: i found this in the docs, does this mean I can just use the ones from the example?

> generally at least one input and output must always be set, and those
>   addresses must adhere to validation rules specific to your Transaction
>   Family

Comment: seems like the inputs and outputs are not the reason as i got it working with the inputs and outputs in the example using the Javascript sdk..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The inputs and outputs are optional. They are used by the Sawtooth validator node to detect invalid changes to state (access to state not in the inputs or outputs list). They also help parallelize transactions as transactions with distinct inputs/outputs lists can be processed in parallel.

In most cases, the creator of the transaction should know what state changes are being made and should be able to set the inputs and outputs lists correctly.  For example, if you debit from a bank account, the inputs and outputs would include the bank account balance.